# Defining determinants as product preserving functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

In most treatments I have seen, determinants of square matrices are either defined via Liebniz's formula, or as the unique function that is multilinear in each row, $0$ if two rows (or columns) are equal and normalised: $D(I)=1$ where $I$ is the idenitity matrix. What if we were to define determninants as product preserving functions namely:
$$D(AB)=D(A)D(B)$$
and normalised $D(I)=1$? This would not determine a unique function as for example, for $1\times 1$ matrices all three $D((a))=1$, $D((a))=a$ and $D((a))=a^3$ satify the two properties. So my question is what are the "weakest" other conditions we need to impose to uniquely define the function and of course, for this definition to be equivalent with the standard one? Multilinearity seems to be such a condition but I am wondering if it can be replaced via something "simpler"

Comment: @AndreasH.: The determinant of the identity matrix is indeed 1 regardless of its size. I suspect you have the trace in mind rather than the determinant.

Comment: @brad: yes, of course. thanks.

Comment: You might try homogeneity: $D(kB) = k^nD(B)$ for $k$ a scalar and $n$ the size of the $B$.

Comment: @AdamSaltz Will that suffice?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost sufficient that D be *homogeneous*: $D(kA) = k^nD(A)$ for an n-by-n matrix $A$.  But this isn't enough.  You can find mor information here: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2319807?uid=3739696&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21103401824783